# OAuth 2.0. No session? (stateless)

Tags: session, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, stateless

I'm going to implement **OAuth 2.0** and **REST API** with it

to grant different permissions per users and also to scale well.

To scale well, **stateless** is easier because there is

**NO** file, database, in-memory based session with it.

---

Below is how I understand OAuth 2.

1. OAuth Server give an access token to a user.
2. The user's access token is stored in cookie.
3. When user access to REST API, user sends with the access token.
4. Server receives request with access token.
5. Server find out whether access token is valid and the user has permission to do request.
6. Do or reject based on user's privilege.

---

So I do not have to worry about session storage. Right?

Comment: Take a look at this library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-oauth2

Comment: I still think no one answered the exact question. By session storage, I am assuming inside a DB or Redis.
So I am using Oauth 2.0 and I only need to store Refresh Tokens against the users in my DB. I am using the Implicit Grant Flow. Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are describing here, is the OAuth 2 [Implicit Grant flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28#page-8). OAuth 2 also includes three other flows, but as it seems that your ressource owner (the user) is initiating requests using browser side Javascript (you were talking about cookies), this is the flow you should go for.

On client side, OAuth only requires you to store the `access_token` for accessing protected ressources (and a [`refresh_token`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28#page-10) if you're going for an expiring `access_token`).

Comment: To check against access token he'll have to have a db server side. ;)

Comment: Sure, on server side he has to know for each access token on which user's behalf it was issued and which scopes were granted. Optionally he could also remember and check the allowed `redirect_uri` for better security. If that is what he meant with "session storage", I misunderstood the question ;)

Comment: Forget the part about the `redirect_uri`, it's wrong. I should go to bed ;)

Answer (score 4):

A more recent innovation is JWT - JSON Web Token.

Here is a link to the spec:
[JWT - JSON Web Token](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html)

JWT is a method of using Hashed tokens using a Hashing method such as HMAC which stands for a Hash-based Message Authentication Code.  Because the token is hashed using a secret key, the server can determine if the token has been tampered with.

Here is an example method to create a Hashed token for JWT:

```
    public String createTokenForUser(User user) {
        byte[] userBytes = toJSON(user);
        byte[] hash = createHmac(userBytes);
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(170);
        sb.append(toBase64(userBytes));
        sb.append(SEPARATOR);
        sb.append(toBase64(hash));
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Here is an example of decoding a token to ensure it was not tampered with:

```
public User parseUserFromToken(String token) {
    final String[] parts = token.split(SEPARATOR_SPLITTER);
    if (parts.length == 2 && parts[0].length() > 0 && parts[1].length() > 0) {
        try {
            final byte[] userBytes = fromBase64(parts[0]);
            final byte[] hash = fromBase64(parts[1]);

            boolean validHash = Arrays.equals(createHmac(userBytes), hash);
            if (validHash) {
                final User user = fromJSON(userBytes);
                if (new Date().getTime() < user.getExpires()) {
                    return user;
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //log tampering attempt here
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is an article with a more complete example:  [Stateless Authentication](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-2-stateless-authentication/)